# Как обратится к параметризированному конструктору

Tags: java

Есть вот такой класс.

```
public class Passenger {

    Passenger(String name, String lastName, int year, String comfortLevel,
              double carryOn, double baggage, Boolean weapon, Boolean premiumCard){
        name = name; // имя пассажира
        lastName = lastName; // фамилия
        year = year;// полных лет
        comfortLevel = comfortLevel;//класс билета
        carryOn = carryOn;//вес ручной клади
        baggage = baggage;//вес багажа
        weapon = weapon;// наличие оружия
        premiumCard = premiumCard;// наличие дисконтной карты

    }
}
```

Следущий класс SellTicket

```
public class SellTicket {
    private double[] econom = {8.0, 4.0};// параметры класса вес багажа, ручной клади
    private double[] business = {12.0, 8.0};
    private double[] comfort = {10.0, 6.0};
    private int adult = 18;// возраст
    private int young = 16;
    private int baby = 5;


    void schekPass(Passenger p) {// проверяем в черном списке
        AviaSafe a = new AviaSafe();
        a.checkPassenger(p);
    }

    void sheckYear(Passenger p){// смотрим возраст
        if(p.year >= adult){

        }
        if(p.year >= young){

        }
        if(p.year >= baby){

        }
    }

    void checkComfort(Passenger p) {//
       if(p.comfortLevel == "comfort"){

       }
       if(p.comfortLevel == "business"){

       }
       if(p.comfortLevel == "econom"){

       }
    }

    void sheckWeapon(Passenger p){// наличие оружия
        AviaSafe a = new AviaSafe();
        a.checkWeapon(p);
    }

    void checkDiscountCard(Passenger p){
        if(p.premiumCard){
            //насчитываем авиамили и прочие плюшки
        }
    }
}
```

Не хочу создавать кучу сеттеров, геттеров. Как получить доступ к параметрам конструктора?

Comment: Посмотрите паттерн Builder

Comment: `name = name;` - что это делает?

Comment: извините забыл this. as3.0 дает о себе знать

Answer (score 2):

Если не хотите писать `boilerplate code`, то используйте библиотеку [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)

С ней достаточно будет добавить, только одну аннотацию `@Data`.

Answer (score 1):

пока придумал такой вариант.

```
public class Passenger {

private String name;
private String lastName;
private int year;
private String comfortLevel;
private double carryOn;
private double baggage;
private Boolean weapon;
private Boolean premiumCard;

Passenger(String name,String lastName, int year, String comfortLevel,
          double carryOn, double baggage, Boolean weapon, Boolean premiumCard) {

    setName(name);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setYear(year);
    setComfortLevel(comfortLevel);
    setCarryOn(carryOn);
    setBaggage(baggage);
    setWeapon(weapon);
    setPremiumCard(premiumCard);

}

private void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

private void setLastName(String name){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

private void setYear(int year){
    this.year = year;
}

public int getYear(){
    return year;
}

private void setComfortLevel(String comfortLevel){
    this.comfortLevel = comfortLevel;
}

public String getComfortLevel(){
    return comfortLevel;
}

private void setCarryOn(double carryOn){
    this.carryOn = carryOn;
}

public double getCarryOn(){
    return carryOn;
}

private void setBaggage(double baggage){
    this.baggage = baggage;
}

public double getBaggage(){
    return baggage;
}

private void setWeapon(Boolean weapon){
    this.weapon = weapon;
}

public Boolean getWeapon(){
    return weapon;
}

private void setPremiumCard(Boolean premiumCard){
    this.premiumCard = premiumCard;
}

public Boolean getPremiumCard(){
    return premiumCard;
}
```

}

Comment: Либо делаешь private поля и делаешь геттеры, сеттеры. Либо делаешь public поля и общаешься к ним так <object>.<fildName>.

Comment: вопрос будет ли второй вариант безопасен?